# How to enable NextJS "next/future/image"?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to use Next.js `next/future/image` experimental component.

I upgraded the Next.js version in `package.json` to `"next": "^12.2.0"`.

Here's my `next.config.js` file:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    strictMode: true,
    experimental: {
        images: {
            allowFutureImage: true,
        },
    },
    images: {
        domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com',],
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

It doesn't allow me to use this feature. Here's the error message in the browser console:

> `` Error: The "next/future/image" component is experimental and may be subject to breaking changes. To enable this experiment, please include `experimental: { images: { allowFutureImage: true } }` in your next.config.js file. ``

Comment: I see that you have tried to add it in the configuration. Indeed, depending on your version you should be able to use it without adding it. [See the answer of sayandcode.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73969144/1134080)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**For Next v13 users:**

I believe `next/future/image` is now the default `Image` component. So no additional work necessary! Just import and use

```
import Image from 'next/image'
```

**For Next v12.3 users**(like the author of this question)

You don't need to add anything to the config to use `future/image`. The future image is now stable. Just use it directly by importing

```
import Image from 'next/future/image'
```

In fact, adding an `images` property to the config will cause an error, since the config schema has been updated. So **don't do that**.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    images: { // This will cause an error
      allowFutureImage: true,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: This is correct, from v12.3.0 and up.

Comment: Please edit the answer and put the next 13 users answer first and then the other one.
I made the mistake to first implement the first answer, and then the second answer : )
Also instead of Next 13, write `^Next v12.3.0`

Comment: @GabrielArghire Done! Although, I didn't understand your qualms with the versioning. Calling it Next13 intuitively conveys that there are breaking changes.

Comment: Thank you for your edit! I wanted to say that the import `import Image from 'next/image'` imports future image since Next `v12.3.0`, not since Next `v13`, as per the first comment of this answer says.

Comment: @GabrielArghire Ahh I see. There's some confusion on that point. I believe v12.3 imports the future image as `next/future/image` as per [this release blog](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-3#image-component). Only v13 really made in part of the mainstream components

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for the details provided!

Answer (score 7):

The solution that worked for me was to add the experimental rule and stop the nextjs server and restart it. Then it would start working

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    images: {
      allowFutureImage: true,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: This is what I had in the settings already. Restarting the development server worked for me

Comment: Yes restarting will make it work

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with NextJS version 12.3.1, and if I enable it in the next.config.js then I get an ugly warning on the terminal. So it is best to just `import Image from "next/future/image"` and not add the config to avoid the Warning. Hope others using 12.3.1 find this useful ( using future/image gets rid of the nasty wrapper divs/spans around the  )

Warning I'm seeing with config in place:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The value at .experimental has an unexpected property, images, which is not in the list of allowed properties (adjustFontFallbacks, amp, appDir, browsersListForSwc, cpus, craCompat, disableOptimizedLoading, disablePostcssPresetEnv, esmExternals, externalDir, fallbackNodePolyfills, forceSwcTransforms, fullySpecified, gzipSize, incrementalCacheHandlerPath, isrFlushToDisk, isrMemoryCacheSize, largePageDataBytes, legacyBrowsers, manualClientBasePath, modularizeImports, newNextLinkBehavior, nextScriptWorkers, optimizeCss, optimisticClientCache, outputFileTracingRoot, pageEnv, profiling, proxyTimeout, runtime, scrollRestoration, serverComponents, sharedPool, sri, swcFileReading, swcMinify, swcMinifyDebugOptions, swcPlugins, swcTraceProfiling, urlImports, workerThreads).

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (images) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
```

Comment: In fact, I just realized my example warning  is what @sayandcode meant when he said "don't do that" in his post

Answer (score -1):

in next js 13 it is by default enabled

```
          <div className="relative rounded-md h-full p-3 border-2">
            <Image 
              width="0"
              height="0"
              sizes="100vw"
              className="w-full h-full top-0 left-0 object-cover rounded-2xl"
              src="https://gbpay.uk/assets/images/gbpay-how-it-works.png" 
            />
          </div>
```